# Is it possible to get Service Endpoint from IIS in C#?

Tags: c#, web, url, iis

First of all I'm new to programming and I'm still learning. 
I need to get all service endpoints for my application from `iss`. They are under `Sites -> Default Web Site -> Name(Folder) - > (Here are all Services) under AppFabric EndPoints`. 
This is what I need to go trough all services and get their Endpoints, but I need to do this in `c#` code. I have tried to look for it with the server manager, but I can not find it or maybe its not even possible to find it. 
Does anyone know how to access those endpoints in `c#` and get the `urls`?

Comment: What is "the server manager" you referred to? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.administration.servermanager%28v=vs.90%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 is clearly the way to go, and you simply need to go through its `Sites` property to go down to site/application level. There is no URL related API though, you need to calculate such using site bindings and application paths. You might find some useful examples from Jexus Manager https://github.com/jexuswebserver/JexusManager (though it uses its own Microsoft.Web.Administration implementation).

Comment: Okay thanks, for your help, but i just found out that the business i work for. Has an own WebService for this, so now i dont actually need do this.